# Machshirin and being satisfied with wetting

Tags: mishna, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, grapes-wine, bread, maseches-machshirin

[Mishnah Machshirin 3:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Makhshirin.3.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains that a loaf of bread which is placed over the top of a wine cask and absorbs wine fumes is considered hechsher. But why is this the case, because there is no reason to suppose that the person who placed the bread wanted it to be moistened with wine?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean the loaf of bred placed on top of a wine cask is *hefker* rather than hechsher?

Comment: @JoshK - *hechsher* is the right term here. The central tenet of the masechta is the law of hechsher, which means a drink/beverage defined as one of the seven liquids that make something susceptible to tumah (impurity).

Comment: , indeed following the second pshat of the bartenura it's not the case

Comment: The pashtut is that he takes it here intentionally and know about the absorption. The controversy is about the strongness of the phenomenon.

Comment: @Dov *mukhshar* is the right term

Comment: If after the fact he is happy with it absorbing wine fumes,  it still counts as hechsher. See https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.22a.12?lang=he&with=Mishnah&lang2=he